# Chrome Extension inject callback on webpage's native function call?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback

I have a Chrome Extension which runs on a dedicated domain and manipulates the DOM.  (Everything here is kosher: the user INTENTIONALLY installs this for this specific given site, and even the site owners are aware/support this extension, but they are not able to change its code easily.)

One page loads the content via AJAX, and refreshes a given  every minute or so with a polling AJAX call.  There is a specific function, UpdatePageComplete() that they call at the end of the AJAX sync.  I need that function to then call one of MY Chrome Extension functions, so that I can manipulate the new data (ex: adding `<a href='tel:'` wrappers to any phone numbers, or background-colors to elements with certain contents).

I can't figure out how to inject my own callback into their native functions though.  Is this even possible?  If so, where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past. You can't inject your own callback into their code, but you can:

1. Create a global function for them to call (inject `window.mySpecialFn = () => {...}`)
2. Add a custom event listener on the body, and have their code dispatch that custom event.